# time dimension and milliseconds

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am with a dilemma designing the time dimension, I am not sure if I should include the millisecond in the time dimension or create a dimension for the millisecond grain.

I can see advantages and disadvantages in include the millisecond grain within the time dimensions.

Advantages:

- perform calculations directly over the dimensional keys (date and time dimensions are the only datawarehouse allowed to contain any intelligence in them). And the purpose of the facts table is to **measure response times**.

Disadvantages:

- time dimension gets to big and i might lose query performance.

---

Other information it is important to know:

- Marketing guy told me to expect between 50 million facts per month (we know how they are, I should be prepared for a few more)
- The facts are to be aggregated and in a non-additive way, this is: i want quality of service measures: average (semi-additive), median, percentiles.

  - Each fact have 12 time checkpoints.

Comment: I would include the millisecond grain, and use aggregate tables to improve the queries on slower time dimensions.

Comment: there are 30 billion millisecond in a year. If you don't separate you will have a heck of a big dimension (potentially as many row as in the fact table)

Comment: @momobo i think is a  bit obvious my question is about include the millisecond grain in the time dimension and not about include the millisecond in the date dimension...

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I was thinking on have day aggregations, the problem start the facts are not additive and the aggregations hardly will can be used for further aggregations.

Comment: Without knowing more about your fact tables, I can't make any more suggestions.  I realize that your quality of service measures aren't aggregatable, but they probably can be precalculated for a day or some other time measure.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have misread. Still your time dimension will be very big. Some kind of aggregation (or granularity reduction, they really need microseconds?) will probably be necessary.

Comment: @SQL.injection: What is the lowest granularity of your aggregation? Is it a millisecond? (I doubt) A second? A minute? I would suggest creating a time dimension with that granularity. Than you can have your time with milliseconds or timestamp as milliseconds as a degenerate dimension.

Comment: Just to confirm: a given fact record effectively contains the time that an event occured, it does not contain an event and it's  duration - is that how you're recording it? Consider if there is any value in creating a time dimension. Do you have special attributes to be applied to time? There is always room to be flexible in these data models. It doesn't seem to me that a time dimension adds any value here, perhaps consider saving the time directly in the fact.

Comment: @ElectricLlama i need the time dimension. I need the time dimension because the use case of know at what part of the day the QoS goes down is a use case.

Comment: @ElectricLlama i already changed the design of the fact. now I only store the time of the first event (in second)... and then i store the offset between the relevant events in (millisecond). And i cannot save 12 timestamps per fact on a 50 million fact per month table.

Comment: @SQL.injection: Why can't you store 12 timestamps per fact?  That's about 2 gigabytes a month.  It's up to the business to decide if the information is worth the storage cost.

Answer (score 0):

I think its kind of dimentional data separation which can decrease size of dimension table which it should be,
relative sample would be you may separate dimDate and dimTime although you can have them together, but if not it will create a big dimension table,
now I think a practical solution is to seperate dimMilisecond from dimTime, and bcs its only contain one filed you can only add this to your fact without creating a physical dimMilisecond and it will be kind of Degenerated Dimension Attribute (DDA) in your fact table.

regards.